# Mapbox GL JS: Export map to PNG or PDF?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS version 0.32. Is there a way to export the map to a high-res PNG or PDF?

Obviously, I can just screenshot, but it would be nice if there was a more formal way.

I found [this repo](https://github.com/vicapow/mapbox-gl-js-export), but it looks old and isn't clear how it works.

I tried using [the `preserveDrawingBuffer` option](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/):

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 14,
    center: [-2.0, 53.3],
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});
console.log(map.getCanvas().toDataURL());
```

This outputs a long data URL in the console, but copying and pasting it into [a base64 converter](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/) just seems to produce an empty image.

**UPDATE**: This is my new code, in full:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyXXX';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 14,
    center: [-2.0, 53.3],
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});
var dpi = 300;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'devicePixelRatio', {
    get: function() {return dpi / 96}
});

map.on('load', function () {
    var content = map.getCanvas().toDataURL();
    console.log(content)
});
```

The output to the console is this: http://pastebin.com/raw/KhyJkJWJ

Comment: Well, it is working. Your console output of `content` looks like Ireland, UK and Western Europe to me. Most browsers can view it by simply c&p'ing it in the address bar. To save the png, use [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) instead of `toDataURL()`. And last not least: to render that map in high-res, have a look into https://github.com/mpetroff/print-maps for details.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually worked out that Firefox will do this, but Chrome won't - hence my confusion!

Comment: Is there a way to do this 'headless' I don't have any need for any actual map to be drawn in the browser, I just wanna loop through a bunch of layers taking snapshots to use as thumbnails / previews?

Comment: Yes! The `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` is required!! :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two main questions:

**1. How do I get the map canvas as an image?**

Actually, you are doing the right thing, but just too early. Give that map some time to load and fetch the image data when the `load` event is triggered:

```
map.on('load', () => console.log(map.getCanvas().toDataURL()));
```

**2. How do I get that image in high-res?**

By changing `window.devicePixelRatio` according to your destination dpi, you can trick your browser into generating high-res output. I found that solution in an implementation created by Matthew Petroff, see his code on  https://github.com/mpetroff/print-maps.
This is the trick he's using for generating high-res output:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'devicePixelRatio', {
    get: function() {return dpi / 96}
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/mpetroff/print-maps/blob/69d4a24d90983049b345af17cda19bc3076875ce/js/script.js#L406)

Comment: Thanks! I still have the same problem though even after moving the line to after image load. If I paste the output into an online decoder it says it's invalid: if I paste it into a text file and save it with a `.png` extension, I can't open the file. Are others able to successfully use this method to get PNGs?

Comment: for people wondering why the image is blank... make sure you have `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` in mapbox gl options

Comment: now you can also use `map.setPixelRatio`

Answer (score 7):

I created a simple working example for anybody stumbling upon this thread:

(Thanks @Vic for pointing out the `preserveDrawingBuffer`-option in Mapbox GL JS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #map {
        margin: auto;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <a id="downloadLink" href="" download="map.png">Download ↓</a>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'your-token-here';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        center: [-74.50, 40],
        zoom: 9,
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });

    $('#downloadLink').click(function() {
        var img = map.getCanvas().toDataURL('image/png')
        this.href = img
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The big secret was preserveDrawingBuffer: true
After that it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: preserveDrawingBuffer for the win! Thanks yall!

Answer (score 0):

For better results, you can implement the @watergis/mapbox-gl-export package, it can gives you more options and feature than direct data URL.

Check this link : [mapbox-gl-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@watergis/mapbox-gl-export)

Posting this answer if someone get help from this.