# Export high resolution image from mapbox

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, mapbox-gl-js

I want to export a very high-resolution(12000x9000px) image from mapbox preferably using .net framework.

**I have already tried:**

1. [mapbox-map-image-export](https://github.com/digidem/mapbox-map-image-export). It is not working for me - no errors, no file generated. I know my token is valid because I am using it in a different project. I have already looked at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758253/running-npm-mapbox-map-image-export) post. Details:

   - OS: Win 10
   - Node version: 8.9.4
2. Changing windows DPI to 900 by following this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483449/mapbox-gl-js-export-map-to-png-or-pdf/42509954) and then exporting the map which actually generated the image I was looking for but since it is only the client side, it is of no use.

**Questions:**

1. What am I doing wrong in the 1st approach?
2. Is there a clean way to implement my 2nd approach server side?
3. Please suggest what are the other options.